# How to overwrite output using 2nd action button

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app which writes a dataframe to output when an action button is pressed. This is the "Go" button in the bare-bones example below. I have a reset button which resets the values of the inputs. I'm wondering how I might also reset the output (so it becomes NULL & disappears when "reset" is pressed).

I've tried to pass `input$goButtonReset` to the `eventReactive` function (with the intention of using an if statement inside to indicate which button was making the call) but this didn't seem to be possible.

Any help much appreciated!

```
ui <- fluidPage(title = "Working Title",

sidebarLayout(

  sidebarPanel(width = 6,
  # *Input() functions
  selectInput("Input1", label = h3("Select Input1"),
              choices = list("A" = "A", NULL = "NULL"),
              selected = 1),
  actionButton("goButton", "Go!"),
  p("Click the button to display the table"),
  actionButton("goButtonReset", "Reset"),
  p("Click the button to reset your inputs.")
  ),

  mainPanel(
    # *Output() functions
    tableOutput("pf"))
  )

)

# build the outputs here
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$goButtonReset, {
    updateSelectInput(session, "Input1", selected = "NULL")
  })

  writePF <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    data.frame("test output")
  })

  output$pf <- renderTable({
    writePF()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `reactiveValues` to store the data frame. This worked for me:

```
    ui <- fluidPage(title = "Working Title",

                sidebarLayout(

                  sidebarPanel(width = 6,
                               # *Input() functions
                               selectInput("Input1", label = h3("Select Input1"),
                                           choices = list("A" = "A", NULL = "NULL"),
                                           selected = 1),
                               actionButton("goButton", "Go!"),
                               p("Click the button to display the table"),
                               actionButton("goButtonReset", "Reset"),
                               p("Click the button to reset your inputs.")
                  ),

                  mainPanel(
                    # *Output() functions
                    tableOutput("pf"))
                )

)

# build the outputs here
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  df <- reactiveValues()  

  observeEvent(input$goButton,{    
    df$writePF <- data.frame("test output")    
  })

  observeEvent(input$goButtonReset,{    
    df$writePF <- NULL    
  })


  output$pf <- renderTable({
    df$writePF
  })  

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```